# Rendering in Rails erb of a each_with_index loop through a JSONB array results in duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I am trying to render the following in a view but the outcome (day and array) is duplicated.  This seems to work in a console and removing the time helpers does not help.  I suspect an ERB thing.

The business_hours are stored as JSONB.

Any hints of what I have missed appreciated.

```
company.schedules.last.business_hours returns

=> {"monday_opens_at"=>"08:00:00", "sunday_opens_at"=>"09:00:00", "monday_closes_at"=>"20:00:00", "sunday_closes_at"=>"18:00:00"}


<table class="table table-sm table-borderless text-sm mb-0">
        <% if company.schedules.last.business_hours? %>
          <% I18n.t('date.day_names').each do |day| %>
            <% %w[opens_at closes_at].each_with_object([]) do |time_type, to_return| %>
              <% @hours = to_return << company.schedules.last.business_hours["#{day.downcase}_#{time_type}"]
                  @hours.compact.tap do |hours| %>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="pl-0"><%= "#{day}" %></th>
                      <td class="pl-0 pr-0 text-right"><%= "#{time_helper(hours)}" %></td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <% else %>
            <p> no data available</p>
        <% end %>
      </table>
```

Comment: Why are you using `tap` there?

Comment: without tap it does not render anything

Answer (score 0):

The `to_return` parameter on the `each_with_object` loop is cumulative. When time_type is `opens_at`, you attribute the business hours to `to_return` with `<<` and then you set @hours with the contents of `to_return`.

In the second run, when `time_type` is `closes_at`, you are setting @hours with the contents of `to_return`, which will be the business hours from the first loop plus the business hours from the second (because of the <<). That may be causing the duplication.

Also, we should investigate the `tap`, it should work with a simple `each` in there.